# Show that the general solution to $y^{\prime\prime}-4xy^{\prime}+\left(4x^2-2\right)y=0$ is $y\left(x\right)=C_1\mathrm{e}^{x^2}+C_2x\mathrm{e}^{x^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

> By solving the differential equation
> $$y^{\prime\prime}-4xy^{\prime}+\left(4x^2-2\right)y=0$$
> using the series method, demonstrate that its general solution is
> $$y\left(x\right)=C_1\mathrm{e}^{x^2}+C_2x\mathrm{e}^{x^2}$$
> Here, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary constants of integration.

---

**My attempt and hint**: I've been given a hint that by obtaining recursive relationships for the coefficients of the series, you can calculate several initial terms, and then "guessing" the expression for the $n$-th coefficient (since you know what you should get) you can verify whether it holds true in all cases.

I am not really familiar with this method and would appreciate your help.

Comment: You have to know that $\forall x\in \mathbb R,e ^{x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}$

Comment: First write $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nx^n \text{ then }y'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}\text{ then }y"=...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we don't know the answer.

$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$, $y'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n x^{n-1}$, $y''=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_n x^{n-2}$.

Subing in the given equation $y''-4xy'+(4x^2-2)=0$ we have

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_n x^{n-2}\color{red}{-
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 4na_n x^n}+
\color{purple}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty 4a_n x^{n+2}}\color{red}{-
\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2a_n x^n}=0$$
Separating some initial terms we have
$$2a_2+6a_3x+\sum_{n=4}^\infty n(n-1)a_n x^{n-2}\color{red}{-4a_1x-
\sum_{n=2}^\infty 4na_n x^n}+
\color{purple}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty 4a_n x^{n+2}}\color{red}{-2a_0-2a_1x-
\sum_{n=2}^\infty 2a_n x^n}=0$$
By reindexing the black and the purple series and combining the reds,
$$(2a_2-2a_0)+(6a_3-6a_1)x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n
\color{red}{-\sum_{n=2}^\infty (4n+2)a_n x^n}
+\color{purple}{\sum_{n=2}^\infty 4a_{n-2} x^n}=0$$
Combining all
$$2(a_2-a_0)+6(a_3-a_1)x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty I_n x^n=0\tag1$$
where
$$I_n=(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}-(4n+2)a_n+4a_{n-2}.$$
From $(1)$, $a_2=a_0$, $a_3=a_1.$ We also get the indical equation $I_n=0.$ Solving this equation recursively with $a_0=1, a_1=0$ and $a_0=0,a_1=1$ separately, we can obtain the two independent solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. Btw, can you fill up the steps between first two equations, I think i made some errors but I can't figure out where

Comment: I tried to do your request step. But I messed it up and cancelled. I will try later. @Bagaringa

Answer (score 1):

You are given a candidate for the solution. It has the required amount of independent parameters or integration constants. So you just have to test if inserting the function satisfies the differential equation.

Or you could detect the common factor in the proposed solution and set $y(x)=u(x)e^{x^2}$ and extract the differential equation for $u$. Then the claim becomes almost trivial.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions